# Subset a list without knowing its structure in r

Tags: r

I have a list in R:

```
my_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = list(d = 4, e = 5))
```

Suppose I don't know the structure of the list, but I know that somewhere in this list, there is an element named `d`, nested or not.  I would like to:

1. Subset that list element, without knowing the structure of the master list that contains it
2. Know the name of its parent list (i.e. element `c`)

Is there an easy method / package that can solve this seemingly simple problem?

Comment: Can you provide sample output?

Comment: To me, it's clear that a method that recurses based on `is.list` is appropriate. In order to track the "parent name", we'd need some logic similar to python's `os.walk` functionality, but that's not too hard. Ultimately, the "how" here depends heavily on your needed output. What have you tried so far, btw?

Comment: @r2evans I feel like `rapply` might come into play but I'm waiting to see what the expected output actually looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another recursive approach, very similar to @JosephWood's answer, that generalizes the solution such that you can search for multiple elements at the same time, and find *all* the matching elements, if there are multiple:

```r
find_all <- function(x, elements) {
  lists <- vapply(x, is.list, logical(1)) # find sublists

  # find all elements in sublists
  out <- lapply(x[lists], find_all, elements)
  out <- out[!vapply(out, is.null, logical(1))]

  # output any found elements
  if (any(elements %in% names(x)))
    out <- c(out, x[names(x) %in% elements])

  if (length(out) == 0) NULL else out
}
```

The example problem:

```r
my_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = list(d = 4, e = 5))
str(find_all(my_list, "e"))
#> List of 1
#>  $ c:List of 1
#>   ..$ e: num 5
```

And @JosephWood's exotic example complicted further:

```r
exotic_list <-
  list(
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = list(d = 4, e = 5),
    f = list(g = 6, h = list(k = 7, j = 8)),
    l = list(m = 6, n = list(o = 7, p = 8)),
    q = list(r = 5, s = 11),
    t = 12,
    n = 13
  )

str(find_all(exotic_list, c("n", "q")))
#> List of 3
#>  $ l:List of 1
#>   ..$ n:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ o: num 7
#>   .. ..$ p: num 8
#>  $ q:List of 2
#>   ..$ r: num 5
#>   ..$ s: num 11
#>  $ n: num 13
```

---

Using the [`purrr` package](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) we could also get rid of the `vapply`s, making the
function a little bit more succinct, and perhaps a bit more readable, too:

```r
library(purrr)

find_all2 <- function(x, elements) {
  # find all elements in sublists
  out <- map(keep(x, is.list), find_all, elements)
  out <- compact(out) # drop nulls

  # output any found elements
  if (any(elements %in% names(x)))
    out <- c(out, x[names(x) %in% elements])

  if (length(out) == 0) NULL else out
}

identical(
  find_all(exotic_list, c("n", "q")),
  find_all2(exotic_list, c("n", "q"))
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This is really neat! The `reprex` package looks awesome as well.

Comment: It is awesome! Especially when your code produces plots: automatic uploading to imgur is amazing.

Comment: Love this solution, especially since I can keep this in the tidyverse.  I'll have time to review in more detail in a few hours.

Answer (score 4):

I'm implementing the suggestion by @r2evans.  I'm sure this can be improved:

```
getParentChild <- function(lst, myN) {
    myFun <- function(lst, myN) {
        test <- which(names(lst) == myN)
        if (length(test) > 0)
            return(lst[test])

        lapply(lst, function(x) {
            if (is.list(x))
                myFun(x, myN)
        })
    }

    temp <- myFun(lst, myN)
    temp[!sapply(temp, function(x) is.null(unlist(x)))]
}

getParentChild(my_list, "d")
$c
$c$d
[1] 4
```

Here is a more complicate example that illustrates how `getParentChild` shows lineage when there are multiple children/grandchildren.

```
exotic_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = list(d = 4, e = 5), f = list(g = 6, h = list(k = 7, j = 8)), l = list(m = 6, n = list(o = 7, p = 8)), q = list(r = 5, s = 11), t = 12)

getParentChild(exotic_list, "n")
$l
$l$n
$l$n$o
[1] 7

$l$n$p
[1] 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the following will do what you want.

```
wanted <- "d"

inx <- grep(wanted, names(unlist(my_list)), value = TRUE)
unlist(my_list)[inx]
#c.d 
#  4

sub(paste0("(\\w)\\.", wanted), "\\1", inx)
#[1] "c"
```